# IBM Liberty Developer Tools Not Showing Up in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, open-liberty

I installed the IBM Liberty Developer Tools in eclipse, but Websphere Liberty is not showing up in the server tab.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

https://dzone.com/articles/java-9-on-java-ee-8-using-eclipse-and-open-liberty

[image]

Comment: which version of eclipse and which version of the Liberty Developer Tools are you using?

Comment: eclipse 2021-03 & IBM Liberty Developer Tools 21.0.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That article is a little out of date with how things are currently set up. If you want to use Open Liberty you need the developer tools from the Open Liberty site https://openliberty.io/downloads/#eclipse_developer_tools , not the Eclipse Marketplace - that one is for commercial versions of Liberty.

Comment: that works for Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers & Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.  thank you

Comment: It worked also for me

Comment: it is not working for STS4

Comment: Try STS4 with underlying 2022-09 Eclipse (4.25). Doubt it will work on the latest Eclipse version.